# Boolean value gets inserted into character varying field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.1 will happily insert a boolean value into a varchar field. My expectation is that this would fail because I'm inserting data of the wrong type, and I'd like that to call out an error in my application logic. Is there any way to make this the default behavior, apart from making a trigger or constraint for every single varchar field?

```
CREATE TABLE
foo
(
    text_field CHARACTER VARYING(32)
);
```

Both these insert 'false' into text_field:

```
INSERT INTO foo (text_field) VALUES (FALSE);
INSERT INTO foo (text_field) VALUES (CAST('f' AS BOOLEAN));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because PostgreSQL will accept any expression (in an `INSERT` statement) with a type that can automatically converted to that column's type (more precisely, where an [`ASSIGNMENT` or `IMPLICIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) cast exists between those two types: this is why these casts exists for the first place). F.ex:

```
-- lets see what casts exists to boolean & text
-- "castcontext" is 'a' for ASSIGNMENT, 'i' for IMPLICIT and 'e' for EXPLICIT casts
select castsource::regtype::text,
       casttarget::regtype::text,
       castcontext
from   pg_cast
where  casttarget in ('boolean'::regtype, 'text'::regtype);

create table foo (
  varchar_field varchar,
  text_field    text,
  bool_field    boolean
);

-- these are equivalents, because of some casts
insert into foo values ('false', 'false', 'false');
insert into foo values (false, false, false);
-- this will throw an error
insert into foo values (0, 0, 0);
```

Okay, I cheated a little. There is a special case. When you write a *string* literal (like `'false'`), it has an `unknown` type. Unknown values always passed to the actual column type's [input function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html#AEN77336). True `text` typed literals looks a little different: `text 'false'`. If you look again the default casts PostgreSQL provides, you can see that there is no cast from `text` to `boolean`. That's why this last statement will fail:

```
insert into foo values (text 'false', text 'false', text 'false');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8793/7)

**Edit**: So, there is an `ASSIGNMENT` cast from `boolean` to `text` by default (& there is one to `character varying` also). That's why your table's `text_field` accepts boolean input.

Answer (score 1):

> My expectation is that this would fail because I'm inserting data of the wrong type . . .

SQL statements often involve mixing data types. SQL engines (not just PostgreSQL) follow internal rules for silently converting values of one type into values of another type. PostgreSQL's rules are documented in [Type Conversion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv.html).  The rules it follows for inserting values are in [Value Storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-query.html).

Although it *might* be possible to alter the contents of the pg_cast system catalog (I don't know), I think that's a *really* bad idea. For one thing pg_cast isn't backed up by pg_dump. Disaster recovery might easily put the dbms in a state you don't expect, and it would be hard to troubleshoot.

I think your best bet is to stop inserting Boolean values into columns they shouldn't appear in. Seriously, *why* is application code doing something like setting a column like "city" to False?

Your next best bet is to add a CHECK constraint.

```
alter table foo
add constraint disallow_tf_text_field
check (lower(text_field) not in ('t', 'f', 'true', 'false', 'y', 'n', 'yes', 'no', 'on', 'off', '1', '0'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The intent of the code is to store a string in the field. PHP does $text = substr($text, 0, 32);. This works as expected most of the time, but returns false instead of "" if $text has 0 length. Probably switching away from PHP would help. :)

Comment: Well, anything accepted into a varchar(n) column becomes a string. But PHP's error handling is notorious among programmers. For example, `strpos()` can return Boolean false, but it can also return a nonBoolean value that *evaluates* to false. You have to be really careful with PHP's returned values.